# .gitignore is not ignoring file "config.inc.php"

Tags: git

I have a file, "config.inc.php" in my .gitignore file that git is not ignoring. Now, before anyone jumps in with "git rm --cached file", the file has been removed from the repository. And, yes, I am positive it has been removed.

Guessing it is some kind of syntax error. Here is the file:

```
#DB Connect
db_connect.php
dbconnect.php

#KB Ignores
config.inc.php
client_msg.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "syntax" error with your `.gitignore`. It should work as long as the file is not tracked. Despite your insistence, make sure that the file is really not tracked ( using something like `git ls-files --others` )